# Will it be a good idea to launch website in "Beta" version?

Tags: web

We are about to launch a website? We are thinking of launching it with "Beta" version with real data. Means it will have all features that it is supposed to have, real world data (no dummy data) and then we will keep it under "Beta" version for few months and will keep checking the feedback and how it is working.

Will it be a good idea to launch website in "Beta" version? Will it make any negative impact on users?

Answer (score 1):

Its the best way to proceed as such, as you will be able to:

1. monitor performance in real time, since you can't really check it in testing environment given the number of users that will be accessing it on live.
2. in case of any error, which might have evade your test cases, the users can test it for you (*provided there's a user feedback form*).
3. For security testing, its best to check it on a hosted environment than testing on local.

Above are only some of the advantages of hosting a 'beta' version prior to launching the complete site. There must be some more. :-)

Comment: What i am saying is that it will be in beta for public access till few month. Will it make any -ve impact?

Comment: No, as long as the required info is being displayed, it would not make any negative impact. However, do inform the user (clearly) that it is a beta version. Mentioning it already meant that the website is not a final version.